# Deleting the Registry key & values on NSIS

Tags: nsis

i was trying to delete the regkey key & value by using the following commands(DeleteRegKey,DeleteRegValue),
But in the both cases the registry key & value is not getting deleted. Is there any other way do this activity.

Section test

```
    WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Management System\Shared ExchData" \
    "DRIVE_MON" "Monday"

    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Management System\Shared ExchData"
    DeleteRegValue HKLM "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Management System\Shared ExchData" "DRIVE_MON"
```

SectionEnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your installer is 32-bit then use `HKLM "SOFTWARE\Management System\Shared ExchData"` to access the 32-bit key.

`SetRegView` can be used to choose between the 32 & 64 bit views on 64-bit Windows.